# Почему ввод данных работает через группу, а не через ЛС бота в Aiogram при условии проверки is_chat_admin=True

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram, бот

```
from aiogram import types, executor, Dispatcher, Bot
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher import FSMContext
from sqlite_db_pizza import db_start_pizza, create_profile, read_profile
from sqlite_db_personal import db_start_personal, create_profile_adm

from config import TOKENPZ


storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(TOKENPZ)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class GetAdminStates(StatesGroup):

    admin_id = State()
    name_adm = State()
    photo_adm = State()



@dp.message_handler(commands=['moderator'], is_chat_admin=True)
async def get_admin_id(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await GetAdminStates.admin_id.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Полученние ID')

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['admin_id'] = message.from_user.id

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                           'Отправьте свое ФИО <b>(если оно не совпадает, вы будете удалены с БД)</b>',
                           parse_mode='HTML')
    await GetAdminStates.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=GetAdminStates.name_adm)
async def get_admin_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name_adm'] = message.text

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                           'Отправьте свою фотографию <b>(если она не совпадает, вы будете удалены с БД)</b>',
                           parse_mode='HTML')
    await GetAdminStates.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=GetAdminStates.photo_adm)
async def get_admin_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['photo_adm'] = message.photo[0].file_id

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы получили доступ править меню\nЧтобы создать пиццу /create')
    # await create_profile_adm(state)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Данные занесены в БД')
    await state.finish()
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу реализовать так, чтобы данные которые отправляет пользователь в личные сообщения бота воспринимались, почему то бот реагирует только на сообщения, отправленные в группу, возможно это из-за условии в handlers: is_chat_admin=True . Но если его убрать, появляется ещё одна проблема, как сделать проверку на администратора группы, и чтобы никто посторонний её не мог получить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

просто сделай ещё один хендер на эту функцию

```
from aiogram import filters

@dp.message_handler(commands=['moderator'], is_chat_admin=True)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['moderator'], filters.ChatTypeFilter(['private']))
async def...
```

ещё можно вот так (хз зачем это пишу):

убери фильтр (is_admin) из хендлера и сделай проверку внутри функции: если сообщение из группы (или супергруппы) и сообщение не от админа то завершить фунцию

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['moderator'])
async def get_admin_id(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.chat.type in ['group', 'supergroup'] and not message.from_user.id in [member.user.id for member in message.chat.get_administrators()]: return
    await GetAdminStates.admin_id.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Полученние ID')

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['admin_id'] = message.from_user.id

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                           'Отправьте свое ФИО <b>(если оно не совпадает, вы будете удалены с БД)</b>',
                           parse_mode='HTML')
    await GetAdminStates.next()
```